# How to populate a flat array in javascript

Tags: javascript, tree, populate

My goal is to create a tree-like structure that automatically orders the following data.
The subSkills property contains a list of id references to other skills.

```
[
  {
    name: "chess";
    subSkills: [];
    parentId: "games";
    _id: "chess";
  },
  {
    name: "games";
    subSkills: ["chess",...];
    parentId: "";
    _id: "games";
  },
]
```

```
export default interface ISkill {
  name: string;
  subSkills: string[] | ISkill[];
  parentId: string;
  _id: string;
}
```

The result should be something like this.

```
[
 {
  name: "games";
  subSkills: [
    {
      name: "chess";
      subSkills: [{}...];
      parentId: "games";
      _id: "chess";
    }
  ];
  parentId: "";
  _id: "games";
 }, ... {}
]
```

I should note that the function has to be able to handle any level of depth. As I have no experience with
stuff like this, I would appreciate it if anyone could describe their way of thinking.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I have multiple trees/roots in the database. So multiple skills have a "" as parentId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based to my understanding, each object of the given array will be either a root or a child of another root object. I don't know if you mistakenly filled the subSkills array of an object or is it something to be considered so should be replaced with the whole object if found? per my assumption I just don't have subSkills as strings for now, I set all subSkills to empty array to start with, let me know if this something that should be considered please. otherwise you can actually just see if the string is met then you can remove it from the array and replace it with the child object itself.

Here's my solution:

```
const givenArray = [
  {
    name: "chess",
    subSkills: [],
    parentId: "games",
    _id: "chess",
  },
  {
    name: "games",
    subSkills: [],
    parentId: "",
    _id: "games",
  },
  {
    name: "programming dev",
    subSkills: [],
    parentId: "chess",
    _id: "programming",
  },
  {
    name: "basketball 01",
    subSkills: [],
    parentId: "chess",
    _id: "basketball",
  },
];
const skillsAggregator = (skills) => {
  const newSkills = [...skills];

  newSkills.forEach((skill) => {
    if (!!skill.parentId.length) {
      addSubSkills(newSkills, skill);
    }
  });

  return newSkills;
};
const addSubSkills = (skills, currentSkill) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < skills.length; i++) {
    const skill = skills[i];

    if (currentSkill.parentId === skill._id) {
      skill.subSkills.push(currentSkill);
      break;
    }
  }
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(skillsAggregator(givenArray), null, 2));
```

**NOTE**
If you can update your data structure (and you can) to a Map or a literal object, the algorithm will be faster than with array, here's an example with extra deep nesting level:

```
const givenArray = {
  chess: {
    name: "chess",
    subSkills: [],
    parentId: "games",
    _id: "chess",
  },
  games: {
    name: "games",
    subSkills: [],
    parentId: "",
    _id: "games",
  },
  programming: {
    name: "programming dev",
    subSkills: [],
    parentId: "chess",
    _id: "programming",
  },
  basketball: {
    name: "basketball 01",
    subSkills: [],
    parentId: "chess",
    _id: "basketball",
  },
  football: {
    name: "football",
    subSkills: [],
    parentId: "basketball",
    _id: "football",
  },
};
const skillsAggregator = (skills) => {
  const newSkills = { ...skills };

  Object.entries(newSkills).forEach(([id, skill]) => {
    if (!!skill.parentId.length) {
      newSkills[skill.parentId].subSkills.push(skill);
    }
  });

  return newSkills;
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(skillsAggregator(givenArray), null, 2));
```